# Add image field programatically in D7

Tags: 7, entities, media

I'm moving a bunch of info from an xml feed into drupal nodes. I'm a little hung up on adding the image. I'm using php `copy()` to copy the image from a url to my drupal directory. From here, I'm not sure how to insert the field info into the node in such a way that an fid and all of the required data is generated. What is the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, what I came up with here:

```
function save_my_image($uri) {
  //copy file into drupal files directory
  $contents = file_get_contents($uri);
  //then save into drupal's file system
  $file = file_save_data($contents);
  return $file;
}
```

`file_save_data()` (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_save_data/8) will handle creating an fid for the file and keeping track of it generally.. then simply add the fid to the node in question and you should be golden.